# CMake: Setting correct compiler options for one platform only

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I use CMake to generate build files (makefile or project files) across Windows, OSX and Linux, with C and C++ compilers native to those platforms. On Windows I gnerate VS 2010 project, and in Release configuration a following error occures:

> Command line error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Ob2' command-line options are incompatible

Clearly, CMake generates optimization and debug information options which are not compatible.  This is default CMake configuration, I do not setup any special flags.

I fix this by altering /ZI to /Z7 in the project options in Visual Studio, but this makes it annoying to setup continous integration system - I would need to add script to modify a project file.

Can I force CMake to gnerate /Z7 (C7 Compatible debug info) instead of /ZI?

In addition, how can I make it generate this only in Release configuration and not in Debug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think CMake applies `/ZI` to Release flags by default - it's probably being applied elsewhere in your CMakeLists.txt or one of the CMake files included by it.

Nonetheless, you can switch the flag by doing something like:

```
if(MSVC)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "/Z[iI7]" ""
         CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Z7")
endif()
```

The first line strips all `/Zi`, `/ZI` and `/Z7` flags if they already exist in the Release flags.  Note the use of `"` round `"${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}"`.  It's important that this CMake variable remains a single string.  If the quotes are removed, the variable becomes a semi-colon separated list (i.e. each space is replaced by a semi-colon) and this is unsuitable for passing to the compiler.

You *can* give conflicting flags here if you want.  So if you removed the `string(REGEX REPLACE ...)` command and simply left the `set` command, `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}` could contain `... /ZI ... /Z7 ..."`, but as long as `/Z7` is the last debug info flag, it "wins" and is the one which finally gets applied.

However, for the tiny amount of effort to clean up the variable first, I feel it's worth stripping conflicting flags.

Comment: +1 for great answer. Your solution actually works, tested it - but the problem was in the CMakeLists.txt file just as you said.