# How to properly turnoff /ZI for a visual studio 17.3.4 cmake project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I have C++ code that only works when inlined. But VC refuse to inline them in debug mode even when `__forceinline` is used. I know I can turn them into macros but that's ugly.

After some googling, I found the culprit is `/ZI` option. I [print all the options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000520/7614469). But cmake doesn't seem to add the `/ZI` option. And [remove all /Z7, /Zi, /ZI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16634299/7614469) doesn't work.

The only way that solved the issue is by adding the line below in `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_compile_options(/ZI-)
```

But it gives me tons of the following warnings

```
Command line warning D9025: overriding '/Zi' with '/ZI'
Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/Z-'
```

Is there a way to turn off /ZI without the warnings?

Comment: Maybe try enabling/allowing inline function expansion with `/Ob1` or `/Ob2`? Maybe the debug build sets `/Ob0` (disable inlining) by default?

Comment: @AdrianMole No luck, and I got tons of `Command line warning D9025: overriding '/Ob0' with '/Ob1'`

Answer (score 1):

CMake is setting `/Zi` and `/Ob0` for debug builds automatically. You can search in `CMakeCache.txt` for both flags, you will find them in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`. The cmake script responsible for that is located in `<cmake-path>\Modules\Platform\Windows-MSVC.cmake`.

You could now remove both flags ([as you said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632578/cmake-setting-correct-compiler-options-for-one-platform-only/16634299#16634299), just use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG`). Consider using a [custom build configuration](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-configurations) instead of changing the debug configuration.